# Access Appannie.com's api using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I'm trying to get some data from appannie.com's api and can't seem to get the basic auth to work.  All I get is 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) error.  Here's what I have:

```
var username = "email@email.com";
var password = "password";
var url = "https://api.appannie.com/v1/accounts";

function make_base_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user + ':' + password;
  var hash = btoa(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
}
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    beforeSend: function (xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(username, password));
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', "application/json");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    fail: function(data) {
        alert("fail");
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that API even supports JSONP?

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain calls are not allowed in jQuery/javascript. For cross domain jQuery ajax calls you have only 2 reliable options:

1: use a proxy script that makes the request for you on the same domain as the page that needs to request the xml

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1430/aspnet-proxy-page--used-for-cross-domain-requests-from-ajax-and-javascript/

2: make the cross-domain server support CORS.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Also there are another option(JSON-P) that is not recommended due to security concerns:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

I think number 1 is applicable in your case.

Comment: They are allowed by the browser in some instances, as you've outlined.

Comment: I was trying to use jsonp.  The code I'm writing is just for personal use not to be published online so I'm not as concerned with security.  Is it possible to use jsonp?

Comment: You cannot use it if their service is not JSONP support. You can ask it from their support team. (Does your service support JSONP?)